# Finding the roots of a function given in terms of another function and its derivative

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

This question came in our yesterday's test:

> Let $ f(x) = (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\dots(x+100) $ and $ g(x) = f(x) \cdot f''(x) - (f'(x))^2 $, then $ g(x) = 0 $ has:
>   (1) no solution
>   (2) exactly one solution
>   (3) exactly two solutions
>   (4) minimum three solutions

What I tried: Let $ f(x) = y $, $ f'(x) = y' $ and $ f''(x) = y'' $. We have:

$$ g(x) = y \cdot y'' - (y')^2 = \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left( \dfrac{y'}{y} \right) \cdot y^2 $$

Clearly the roots of $y$ cannot be the roots of $ g(x) $. So we must have:

$$ \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left( \dfrac{y'}{y} \right) = 0 $$

Using Rolle's Theorem on $y$, we can say that between every two roots of $y$ (i.e. values of $x$ where $y=0$), there will be a $c$ such that $f'(c)=0$. This means that $\dfrac{y'}{y}$ will have $99$ roots. Again using the Rolle's theorem, ... oh no. As I type this, I realize I can't use Rolle's theorem here (since $y'/y$ is discontinuous)!

The answer key says that it has no solution. How do we prove this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.** $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln f(x) = ???$. The expression for $\ln f(x)$ is easier to handle.

> $\ln f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}\ln(x+i)$, hence $\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}\frac{1}{x+i}$, and \begin{align}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln f(x)=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}\frac{1}{(x+i)^2}<0\end{align} Which shows $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\ln f(x)$ has no zero points. Now it remains to check $f(x)f''(x)-(f'(x))^2\not=0$ for $x=-1,-2,-3,\cdots,-100$, which is obvious.

Comment: Hello fellow Portal fan! That's a good tip, but I do not understand how finding the second derivative will help here. We already know that $f'(x)/f(x)$ has 99 roots. But it won't help in finding solutions to $g(x)=0$, since $f'(x)/f(x)$ is discontinuous!

Comment: @FreezingFire You do not need to find their roots in fact. $\ln f(x)$ has a simple expression, which helps to calculate $f'(x)/f(x)$. See my edit :)

Comment: I see now! Thanks a lot! +1.